# Deshabilitar o habilitar un input por medio de un Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera saber si existe alguna función para habilitar u deshabilitar un `INPUT` dependiendo del valor de un `SELECT`

Este es mi código:

```html
<div>
  <select name='id_categoria' id='id_categoria' onchange="carg(1);">
   <option value="1" selected>Clientes</option>
   <option value="2">Empresas</option>
   <option value="3">Personas</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Mi intencion es al seleccionar la opciones 2 o 3 **poder** habilitar el input y de lo contrario si se selecciona la 1 Deshabilitarlo

Comment: Hola David, fatlaria que añadas el input que quieres habilitar/deshabilitar y el codigo que has intentado (ese metodo `carg()`? ) para que nosotros podamos explicarte cómo mejorarlo y que funcione. Un saludo

Comment: este es mi INPUT <input type="text" class="form-control" id="d" name="d" placeholder="Buscar Clientes" onkeyup="carg(1)" disabled>

Comment: y este seria el codigo que intento utilizar

Comment: <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
(function(){
$("#id_categoria").change(function(){
var valor= $("#id_categoria").val();
if (valor==1){
$("#d").selectmenu( "disable" );

}else{
$("#d").selectmenu( "enable" );
}
})
})
</script>

Comment: David, **Edita la pregunta** para añadir la información de los comentarios. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b ¿Sería un duplicado siendo que en la otra pregunta especifica que se use Jquery?

Comment: @FranciscoRomero yo así lo considero porque el código que el autor de esta pregunta, lo hizo con JQuery.

Comment: @lois6b No veo necesario el uso de una librería para algo tan simple como esto. Independientemente de eso, yo creo que no debería ser un duplicado ya que en este caso puede darse posibilidad con Javascript, ya que no especifica.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero y eso es lo bueno de una comunidad. hay diversidad de opiniones. ya veremos en que queda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**JQuery**

Podes hacer uso de los métodos `prop` para asignar el valor a un atributo de una etiqueta HTML. Te recomiendo además que le agregues el atributo `disabled` al input para que por defecto se encuentre deshabilitado.

```js
$( function() {
    $("#id_categoria").change( function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "1") {
            $("#id_input").prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $("#id_input").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <select name='id_categoria' id='id_categoria'>
        <option value="1" selected>Clientes</option>
        <option value="2">Empresas</option>
        <option value="3">Personas</option>
    </select>

    <input id="id_input" type="text" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: Intenta dejar el codigo ejecutable en un snippet para que el autor pueda probarlo ^^

Comment: @lois6b Hecho, gracias por la sugerencia!

Comment: Muchas Gracias popr la Sugerencia @Matias Olivera,@j0se He logrado que mi codigo Funcione!!

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$( function() {
    $("#id_categoria").change( function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "1") {
            $("#d").prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $("#d").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
 </script>

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="d" name="d" placeholder="Buscar Clientes" onkeyup="carg(1)" disabled>

Comment: <select class="form-control input-default" name='id_categoria' id='id_categoria' onchange="carg(1);">
        <option value="1" selected>Clientes</option>
        <option value="2">Empresas</option>
        <option value="3">Personas</option>
       </select>

Comment: asi quedaria mi codigo!! Muchisimas Gracias!!

Comment: @David Te recomiendo que leas  [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para entender cómo funciona el sitio. Resumido: La forma de agradecer es aceptando la respuesta que soluciono tu problema y no dejando comentarios en las respuestas. Muchas gracias

Comment: ok, esta Bien muchas gracias disculpa las molestias ya que soy nuevo en esto...

Answer (score 4):

Puedes pasarle la referencia de tu `select` a tu función `carg` con la palabra reservada `this` y comprobar su valor.

En caso de que las opciones seleccionadas sean la 2 o la 3, habilitar el `input` y en caso contrario deshabilitarlo.

Ejemplo:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');

function carg(elemento) {
  d = elemento.value;
  
  if(d == "1"){
    input.disabled = true;
  }else{
    input.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select name='id_categoria' id='id_categoria' onchange="carg(this);">
      <option value="1" selected>Clientes</option>
      <option value="2">Empresas</option>
      <option value="3">Personas</option>
  </select>
  <input id="input" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_categoria').change(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() === "1") {
      $('#d').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $('#d').prop("disabled", false);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select name='id_categoria' id='id_categoria' >
    <option value="1" selected>Clientes</option>
    <option value="2">Empresas</option>
    <option value="3">Personas</option>
  </select>
  <input id="d" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="test">
</div>
```

Yo lo haria asi, bindearia al change del id_categoria o si ya usas el onchange pues lo meteria dentro de esa funcion... a gusto del consumidor

Answer (score 0):

Usa `option:selected` para sacar el valor del select.
Despues con un `switch` puedes manejar los casos.

```js
$("#btn").prop('disabled', false);
$( "#Select_id").change(function() {
  var selector = $("#Select_id  option:selected").val();
  switch(selector){
    case "1":
      $("#btn").prop('disabled', false);
      break;
    case "2":
      $("#btn").prop('disabled', true);
      break;
    case "3":
      $("#btn").prop('disabled', true);
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select name='Select_nombre' id='Select_id'>
    <option value="1" selected>Clientes</option>
    <option value="2">Empresas</option>
    <option value="3">Personas</option>
  </select>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="BOTON"></input>
```

Comment: Hola @GDP, lo que preguntó el OP es cómo habilitar o deshabilitar un input, pero en tu código lo que haces es mostrarlo/ocultarlo.